# parse variables from url but also change the cell-padding and border and background

Tags: php, parsing, variables, styles

So I am creating a calculator using parsing variables. Whether I enter the values for the variables in the url or in the form, the page should do the calculation. Now x,y,z work perfectly, but I also need to do the same for cellpadding, border and the background colour. How do I use parsing variables to change the actual padding, border and bckgrd colour of the table when the user assign them values? Please helppp ! Thank you so much!

```
<?php
// parse variables from URLs
echo "This is the value of <b>x:</b>  " . $_GET['x'] . ". This is the value of <b>y: </b> " . $_GET['y'] . ".This is the value of <b>z: </b>  " . $_GET['z'] . " , And the title is: " . $_GET['title'] . ".";
?>

<?
$x = $_GET['x'];
$y = $_GET['y'];
$z = $_GET['z'];

$result1 = $x + $y - 2*$z;
$result2 = 2*$x + 4*$y + (3*$z - 80);
$result3 = $result1 + $result2; 

$pad = $_GET['pad'];
$brdr = $_GET['brdr'];
$bckrd = $_GET['bckrd'];
?>

<center><h2> Math </h2></center>
<center> <table  cellpadding=20  border= 5  bgcolor= #FFFFFF>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Mathematical Operation</b></td>
            <td><b>Result</b></td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>x + y - 2 * z</td>
            <td><?echo "$result1";?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2x - 4y + (3z - 80)</td>
            <td><?echo "$result2";?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row2 - Col2 + result of Row3 - Col2</td>
            <td><?echo "$result3";?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
    </center>


<form>
<u>Inputs:</u> <br />
X-value <input type="text" name="x" value=""></input><br />
Y-Value <input type="text" name="y" value=""></input><br />
Z-Value <input type="text" name="z" value=""></input><br />
Title <input type="text" name="title" value=""></input><br />
Table Padding <input type="text" name="pad" value=""></input><br />
Table Border <input type="text" name="brdr" value=""></input><br />
Background Color <input type="color" name="bckrd" value=""></input><br />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT and CALCULATE"></input>
</form>

<?
if ($_GET['submit']) {  
    $result1 = $x + $y - 2*$z;
    $result2 = 2*$x + 4*$y + (3*$z - 80);
    $result3 = $result1 + $result2;     
    }
?>
```

Comment: You should be using $x = (isset($_GET['x'])) ? $_GET['x'] : 0; Also the input element doesn't have/need a closing tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this in order to use PHP variables inside your html:

```
$pad = (isset($_GET['pad'])) ? $_GET['pad'] : 20;
$brdr = (isset($_GET['brdr'])) ? $_GET['brdr'] : 5;
$bckrd = (isset($_GET['bckrd'])) ? $_GET['bckrd'] : "#FFFFFF";

echo "<center><h2> Math </h2></center>";
echo "<center> <table  cellpadding=".$pad." border=".$brdr." bgcolor=".$bckrd.">";
?>
<tr>
    <td><b>Mathematical Operation</b></td>
    <td><b>Result</b></td>  
</tr>
```